# EAP TLS encryption security

Tags: wireless-networking, certificate, tls, client-certificate, peap

Is there any different between "EAP-TLS under PEAP" and "EAP-TLS only"?

Is "EAP-TLS under PEAP" more secure compared to "EAP-TLS only"? As in PEAP, we are not able to see the actual certificate information when the authentication is happening because it is in an encrypted tunnel.

Am I right with the above conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds about right. Both EAP-PEAP and EAP-TLS are *technically* TLS, but the latter implies client-certificate authentication, which in TLS does not conceal that certificate in any way. So nesting EAP-TLS inside a second TLS layer (either inside EAP-PEAP or EAP-**T**TLS) can be done to ensure clients' privacy, especially when roaming. A similar approach is used by IPSec IKEv1.

Comment: Thanks @grawity. However I've been told that EAP-TLS is considered more secure than PEAP, as in various internet discussions.

Comment: @Jess: Mainly because it's client-certificate-based while PEAP tends to use plain passwords. (See similar discussions on SSH passwords vs pubkeys.) Many WPA-Enterprise clients are difficult to configure to properly verify the EAP server (things like domain_suffix_match are usually not in GUI), which is a huge problem for e.g. _eduroam_ networks – but much less so with certificate-based authentication.